# Exceptions are not being caught by catch block in Selenium C-Sharp, directly triggers ExceptionThrown event handler

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception, event-listener

I have a test automation framework which is built on selenium-C#, where i have a `custom exception handler` to deal with different exceptions, this `exception handler` is bind to the selenium listener and gets triggered automatically on any exception thrown. The problem here is, in some cases i would just like to catch the exception and do nothing, like in the example below.

```
try
{
    state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    //Ignore
}
```

But `custom exception handler` gets triggered even before the control come to catch block and the `custom exception handler` terminates the test. Is there a way that takes my control to catch block first and then if the exception is thrown or not being handled then only trigger `custom exception handler` ?

Looking forward for your suggestions :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by "custom exception handler". Do you mean the catch block in the code block, or do you mean that you handle the EventFiringWebDriver.ExceptionThrown event?

Comment: If you custom exception handler eats the exception then this handler won't do anything. Remember exceptions are propagated until handled

Comment: @ArnonAxelrod I have a class "CustomExceptionHandler" which is bind to the EventFiringWebDriver.ExceptionThrown event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the catch clause to execute before the EventFiringWebDriver raises the ExceptionThrown event. However, you can either detach the event handler before executing the command inside the try block and attach it back afterwards, or somehow flag your event handler to not do whatever it normally does.